# Access Google ML engine by iOS application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I followed the following documentation by Google to create ML engine and I deployed my online predicator there:

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/quickstart

Now my question is what is the simplest way I can connect my iOS application to the prepared ML engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request Online Predictions, the quickstart provides how to request online predictions by using either the gcloud tool or the python client library, but you can also use a HTTP Request to the JSON API to get the predictions by using the projects.predict method [1]:

```
POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/{name=projects/**}:predict
```

You just have to add your request body with your list of instances using this JSON format [2]:

```
{
  "instances": [
    <simple list>,
    ...
  ]
}
```

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict

[2] https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/v1/predict-request#request-body

Comment: but it needs the user to authenticate to google account and maybe need the user have access to that

Comment: Oh sure, you can use OAuth 2.0 to authenticate as an end user. This option will allow your application to access resources on behalf of a user. You would need to set the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user

There's also the option to use API Keys:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys